# Concat string and change certain numbers to another number

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, concatenation, charat

I am working on some JavaScript code that will take a string of 6 numbers, like '77668899', and loop over it, and if the number is a 6 I need to change it to an 8 and if it's a 9 I need to change it to a 7. So '77668899' will become '77888877'. And I want to concat this to a new empty string. I'm getting confused on order of syntax, like what order to type my methods in.

I've tried using `charAt` but I think I put it in the wrong place and it made it worse.

```js
var lines = "77669988";
var hexString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (lines[i] === 6) {
    lines[i] = 8;
    lines[i].concat(hexString);
    console.log(lines[i]);
  } else if (lines[i] === 9) {
    lines[i] = 7;
    console.log(lines[i])
    lines[i].concat(hexString);
  } else {
    console.log(lines[i])
    lines[i].concat(hexString);
  }
}

console.log(hexString);
```

It's not changing the numbers. The output is wrong:

```
7
7
6
6
9
9
8
8
```

I want hexString to output: "77888877".

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('77668899'.replace(/6/g,'8').replace(/9/g, '7'))
```

Comment: Can I do this same thing, but I need to concat all the numbers in the exact order (but with the changed numbers) into hexString? Or can I do lines. replace(/6/g, '8').replace(/9/g, '7')?

Comment: Also, I need to keep both strings. I need the original number and the new number.

Comment: I tried this but it outputed the same original number:

var lines= "77669988";

linesPreChange = lines;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

linesPreChange.replace(/6/g, '8').replace(/9/g, '7')

}

linesChange = linesPreChange;

console.log(linesChange);

Answer (score 0):

please remember that string is immutable. Meaning you cannot modify a particular index position and assign a new letter.

Better way is to use the slice method and regex combined as mentioned in the below example.

```
let lines = "77668899"
let hexString = lines.slice(0).replace(/6/g,'8').replace(/9/g, '7');
console.log(hexString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. This is for an I Ching app:

function post2get(frm) {

let initialLines=[];

let changingLines=[];

for (let i=0; i < line.length; i++) {

```
initialLines[i]=line[i];
```

}

for (let i = 0; i < initialLines.length; i++) {

```
let initialValue = initialLines[i];

if (initialValue === 6) {

  initialValue = 7;

} else if (initialValue === 9) {

  initialValue = 8;
}

changingLines[i] = initialValue;
```

}

for (let i = 0; i < initialLines.length; i++) {

```
let initialValue = initialLines[i];

if (initialValue === 6) {

  initialValue = 8;

} else if (initialValue === 9) {

  initialValue = 7;
}

initialLines[i] = initialValue;
```

}

let initialLinesString = initialLines.join("");

let changingLinesString = changingLines.join("");

let initialHexAnswer = hexMap[initialLinesString] || hexMap["1"];

let changingHexAnswer = hexMap[changingLinesString] || hexMap["1"];

$("#initialHexAnswer").html(initialHexAnswer);

$("#changingHexAnswer").html(changingHexAnswer);